# Ubuntu terminal, g++--std=c++0x: command not found

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu, gcc, virtualbox

For school I have to program an Operating systems assignment on an Ubuntu virtual machine. I had the program written and got it to compile correctly yesterday. The program used c++11 librarys and my compiling instruction was:

```
g++ -std=c++11 O2.cpp -lpthread
```

This worked fine and compiled with no errors. When I restarted my virtual machine today any time I use g++ it gives me the error

```
g++--std=c++0x: command not found.
```

It does this error even when I do `g++ --version`

I am not real savvy with linux yet but am wondering what I have screwed up/corrupted. I have reinstalled packages but it gives the same error. Even with programs not requiring c++11. Any idea whats going on? Or how to delete the whole compiler and packages and do a fresh install?

Comment: Is it literally `g++--std=c++0x`? Then you'd have to insert a space between `g++` and `--std=c++0x`.

Comment: @Fytch: make that an answer.

Comment: That is what it is reporting back. I do have a space inbetween. It gives that same error when I do the command g++  --version. So that space is not the issue.

Comment: It sounds like you've redefined `g++` with an alias or function, and the alias is missing the space.

Comment: What is the output of `which g++`?

Comment: @paddy /usr/bin/g++

Comment: Well, stick to the command that works. The one that doesn't isn't too useful.

Comment: @juanchopanza there isn't a command that works?

Comment: What's the output of `type g++`

Comment: "This worked fine and compiled with no errors" That one. Type it again. Exactly the same.

Comment: @juanchopanaza "When I restarted my virtual machine today.....it doesn't work"

Comment: @barmar was correct. My bash alias was incorrect. I am not sure how that happened as I had updated it and it was working fine until today. I didn't change it inbetween it. It was having trouble loading "metadata" as it was throwing error like crazy when I was re-doing my alias in bashrc.